# How to preserve field types after finding (copy) and inserting (paste) item in MongoDB 2.6.12

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

**MongoDB v.2.6.12**

I'm trying to find documents with a filter, replace values for one field and paste them back without id (duplicate them with one simple change).
The code that I'm executing either in "Robo 3T" or in the mongo shell looks like:

```
var items_to_copy = []
var transform_fnc = function(row) {
    print("max_comments: " + typeof row.max_comments + " " + row.max_comments);
    row.some_string_field = "some value"
    items_to_copy.push(row)
}
db.getCollection('my').find(query_select, {_id:0}).forEach(transform_fnc);
db.getCollection('my').insertMany(items_to_copy)
```

Output:

```
// max_comments: number 100
// max_comments: number 100
// ...
```

The code works, but the problem is that after inserting I see that *some* of the numeric fields such as `max_comments` have become to Double (`100.0`). But in the original document they were Int32 (`100`).

How to copy documents preserving all original types?

P.S.: Also in the mongo shell I don't see any output from the "print" function but all other logic works.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, I didn't find any other solutions except this one:

1. RUN in the shell:

   ```
   ➔ mongoexport --host mongo.local.host --db mydatabase --collection mycollection --query '{"some": "filter"}' --out /tmp/output.json
   2018-02-08T14:12:06.228+0200    connected to: mongo.local.host
   2018-02-08T14:12:06.745+0200    exported 62 records
   ```
2. EDIT `/tmp/output.json`
3. SEARCH AND DELETE content by regex `"_id":\{"\$oid":"[a-z0-9]+"\},` to remove exist IDs.
4. MODIFY any values that should be different.
5. SAVE `/tmp/output.json`
6. RUN in the shell:

   ```
   mongoimport --host mongo.local.host --db mydatabase --collection mycollection --file /tmp/output.json
   2018-02-08T14:16:46.112+0200    connected to: mongo.local.host
   2018-02-08T14:16:46.941+0200    imported 62 documents
   ```

After this all integers have stayed integers.

But I still very welcome other advices.